# App Installation Failed and lost Device Management in iPhone device after solving the provisioning profile problem

Tags: ios, iphone, installation

0

Although this seems to be an issue with Apple, I've been able to find a temporary solution which has worked for me:

Open your project in XCode.
Select your project from the project navigator and then select your target from the column.
Click on the General tab and under the Signing section, make sure "Automatically manage signing" is enabled.
Click on the Capabilities tab and turn On both the "App Groups" and "Keychain Sharing" settings. This might raise an "Automatic signing failed" popup error, just click cancel to make it go away.
This should generate a entitlements file for you named nameProject.entitlements in the project folder of your project navigator.
Move this entitlements file outside of the folder, just below your project file.
Select your target again and return to the Capabilities tab to turn Off both the "App Groups" and "Keychain Sharing" settings. This again might raise an "Automatic signing failed" popup error, just click cancel to make it go away.
Now select your project above the target and go to Building Settings tab.
Scroll down to the Code Signing Identity setting under the Signing header and select iOS Developer from each drop down.
Under the above Signing header, double click the text field beside the Code Signing Entitlements and enter the name of your entitlements file, nameProject.entitlements.
You should now no longer have the Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "Project" target's entitlements. error. Hopefully this helps!

This is by @Zameer.

I have done this to solve the provisioning profile problem but now having I have 'App Installation Failed' problem and I couldn't install the app on my iPhone device.

Answer (score 0):

This whole issue is such a mess due to certification issues over at Apple. There's a fair chance that after installation you'll get an error saying that the device denied a launch request, but if you're up for some attempts at a workaround you can either:

1. Create new user on your Mac

**Or**

2. Go into the keychain and under System, All Items -> delete certificate Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority

The idea behind it is that you get a new certificate (which is necessary to install and launch apps on the iDevice. YMMV because the whole crux of the issue is that distribution of valid certificates is impaired at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @Prolix! Do I really need to create a new user?

Comment: Oh no, you can try either, no 1 basically has the same effect as no 2 (in theory, the idea is to fetch a new certificate)

Comment: How can I get a new certificate?

Comment: Now I have 4 errors: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -25307.); No signing certificate "iOS Development" found
; Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.***" doesn't support the App Groups and Keychain Sharing capability; Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.***" doesn't include the com.apple.security.application-groups and keychain-access-groups entitlements.